# Building a ROS Package CMake Error

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:156 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'TinyXML' which must be find_package()-ed
  before.  If it is a catkin package it can be declared as CATKIN_DEPENDS
  instead without find_package()-ing it.
```

please i need help .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105941/building-a-ros-package-cmake-error/) by [M Samir](https://answers.ros.org/users/9326/m-samir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A little more detail about the package you are trying to make would be helpful.

Based on the output it looks like you may have not declared a dependency correctly, or declared TinyXML as a dependency but do not have TinyXML installed or set up correctly.

First, I would look here: http://wiki.ros.org/tinyxml

That will probably solve your problem.

Otherwise, I would take a look here for an overview: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml

---

Originally posted by [chase](https://answers.ros.org/users/9066/chase/) with karma: 88 on 2013-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1